# Angular 7 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, api, aplicação-web, angular-7

Estou estudando angular e decidi fazer um buscador de filmes bem simples. Gostaria de colocar os elementos do filme na tela, mas o retorno do meu `get` tem sido um object. Tenho quebrado a cabeça pra tentar fazer-lo exibir. Depois de ler muito, vi que o `ngfor` não consegue exibir os elementos. Alguém pode me dizer alguma forma de converter o object pra `array`. Poderia ser uma ou outra solução de como conseguir pegar os elementos desse object e exibir na tela.

**film-placehold.component.ts**

```
import { Film } from './../models/films';
import { FilmsService } from './../services/films.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-film-placehold',
  templateUrl: './film-placehold.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./film-placehold.component.css']
})
export class FilmPlaceholdComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private serviceFilms: FilmsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFilms();
  }

  getFilms(){
    this.serviceFilms.getFilmsService().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        //console.log(data);
        this.serviceFilms.filmes = data //as Film[]
        console.log(this.serviceFilms.filmes)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**film.service.ts**

```
import { Film } from './../models/films';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilmsService {


  url='https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=x-men&apikey=e03a9ac8'; 

  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  }

  filmes:Film[]

  getFilmsService(): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url)
  }

  getSearchFilmeService(movieName){
    return this.httpClient.get<Film[]>(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movieName}&apikey=e03a9ac8`)
  }
  
}
```

**filmplacehold.html**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <li *ngFor="let filme of serviceFilms.filmes">
        {{filme.Title}}
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro vc está errando na variável, está fazendo o **ngFor** referente a uma variável do tipo service `(serviceFilms)`, teria que criar uma variável no componente para guardar o retorno do service e trabalhar encima dela. Segundo, pela **[url](https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=x-men&apikey=e03a9ac8)** passada, o retorno é um **`objeto`** que contém o atributo `Search` e que por sua vez possui um **`array`** de objetos com as informações sobre os filmes dentro. Logo teria que acessar a propriedade para conseguir percorrer o array:

**TS:**

```
 import { Film } from './../models/films';
 import { FilmsService } from './../services/films.service';
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-film-placehold',
   templateUrl: './film-placehold.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./film-placehold.component.css']
 })
export class FilmPlaceholdComponent implements OnInit {
  public films: Film[];

  constructor(private serviceFilms: FilmsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getFilms();
  }

  getFilms(){
     this.serviceFilms.getFilmsService().subscribe(data => {
        this.films = data["Search"];  // acessa a propriedade Search
        console.log(filmes);  // deverá exibir um array de objetos com os filmes 
     })
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <li *ngFor="let filme of films">
      {{ filme.Title }} - {{ filme.Type }} - {{ filme.Year }}
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa, obrigado por esclarecer Andrade, Funcionou! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nesse exemplo no ngFor está acessando serviceFilmsRender.filmes, mas acredito que o response seja algo como serviceFilmsRender.results, no console.log é possível identificar a estrutura devolvida.

```js
 constructor(
 public serviceFilmsRender;
) { }

getFilms(){
 this.serviceFilms.getFilmsService().subscribe((data: Array<Object>) => {
   console.log(data);
   this.serviceFilmsRender = data;
 });
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
 <li *ngFor="let filme of serviceFilmsRender.filmes">
    {{filme.Title}}
 </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

}